# Visiting visa for Nigeria

Tags: visas, canada, standard-visitor-visas, embassies, nigeria

I am retired, age 73, I want to visit a friend in Nigeria. What alternative letter for NOC will I present since I don't work or school?

Comment: What is “NOC” ?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica *No Objection Certificate*. Typically from an employer, or from a school/university if the visa applicant is a student, it helps to prove ties to home and seems to be prevalent in India in particular. Can’t for the life of me see why a NOC would be relevant for a 73 year old applicant, or who would give it if it were.

Comment: @Traveller Thanks. A bureaucratic triumph, for sure.

Comment: A NOC helps to demonstrate an applicant has meaningful ties to their country of residence that would compel them to return there at the end of a proposed visit. A NOC does not seem relevant to your personal circumstances, you should provide evidence of eg property owned, savings, family ties etc instead

Comment: No idea what your personal circumstances are, but the general theme of "I want to visit a friend in Nigeria" is often associated with various kinds of financial scams that are pervasive today. If this is a friend who you personally know and has travelled to Nigeria and wants you to come visit, sure. If this is somebody you have never actually met who has invited you to come to Nigeria and is helping you arrange details for your visit, please be very careful. Ask somebody you trust in your local community whether it feels right.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you *want to visit a friend in Nigeria*, you can just apply for a **visitor visa** as on [this page of OIS Services](https://oisservices.com/visas-det.php?id=MTgz), the agency that deals with the applications on behalf of Nigerian embassies:

> Apply for a Tourist Visa if you are traveling to Nigeria to explore the country without an invitation letter.
>
> Apply for a Visitor Visa if you are traveling to Nigeria to visit someone who you know and who has provided you with an invitation letter along with a copy of their passport.

In my recent experience (traveling last month from Italy) a letter from me to the embassy and an invitation letter from my Nigerian friend to the embassy (consistent to each other) were enough to apply. Unfortunately I have no idea if different conditions apply to Canadian travelers (as in the tags). Anyway I now see from their website linked above that Canada is one of the locations where you can find OIS Services in the world.